# Deep copy of an object array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, object, copy

I want to make a deep copy of an object array using a constructor.

```
public class PositionList {
    private Position[] data = new Position[0];

public PositionList(PositionList other, boolean deepCopy) {
        if (deepCopy){
            size=other.getSize();
            data=new Position[other.data.length];
            for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            data[i]=other.data[i];
            }
```

However, what I have above for some reason is not working. I have automated tests that I run, and its failing those tests. So theres an error an here that Im not sure what it is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you have implemented is a **shallow** copy.  To implement a **deep** copy, you must
change

```
data[i] = other.data[i];
```

to some thing that assigns a **copy** of `other.data[i]` to `data[i]`.  How you do this depends on the `Position` class.  Possible alternatives are:

- a copy constructor:

  `data[i] = new Position(other.data[i]);`
- a factory method:

  `data[i] = createPosition(other.data[i]);`
- clone:

  `data[i] = (Position) other.data[i].clone();`

Notes:

1. The above assume that the copy constructor, factory method and clone method respectively implement the "right" kind of copying, depending on the Position class; see below.
2. The `clone` approach will only work if `Position` explicitly supports it, and this is generally regarded as an inferior solution.  Besides, you need to be aware that the native implementation of `clone` (i.e. the `Object.clone()` method) does a shallow copy<sup>1</sup>.

In fact the general problem of implementing deep copying in Java is complicated.  In the case of the `Position` class, one would assume that the attributes are all primitive types (e.g. ints or doubles), and therefore a deep versus shallow copying is moot.  But if there are reference attributes, then you have to rely on the copy constructor / factory method / clone method to do the kind of copying that you require.  In each case it needs to be programmed in.  And in the general case (where you have to deal with cycles) it is difficult and requires each class to implement special methods.

There is one other *potential* way to copy an array of objects.  If the objects in the array are *serializable*, then you can copy them by using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` serialize and then deserialize the array.  However:

- this is expensive,
- it only works if the objects are (transitively) serializable, and
- the values of any `transient` fields won't be copied.

Copying by serialization is not recommended.  It would be better to support cloning or some other method.

All in all, deep copying is best avoided in Java.

Finally, to answer your question about the `Position` classes copy constructor works, I expect it is something like this:

```
public class Position {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    ...
    public Position(Position other) {
        this.x = other.x;
        this.y = other.y;
    }
    ...
}
```

As @Turtle says, there's no magic involved.  You implement a constructor (by hand) that initializes its state by copying from an existing instance.

---

<sup>1 - It is specified that the Object implementation of `clone()` does a shallow copy, but this may be overridden. The javadoc for `clone` specifies the "contract" as follows:</sup>

> <sup>*"Creates and returns a copy of this object. The precise meaning of "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The general intent is that, for any object x, the expression: `x.clone() != x` will be true, and that the expression: `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()` will be true, but these are not absolute requirements. While it is typically the case that: `x.clone().equals(x)` will be true, this is not an absolute requirement."*</sup>

<sup>Nothing in the "contract" talks about deep versus shallow copying.  So if you are going to use `clone` in this context, you need to know how the actual classes `clone` method behaves.</sup>

Comment: The copy constructor is the one I need. The one you have above worked perfectly, but I dont understand it. So we're creating a new Position, but what is this argument that we feed it, other.data[i]? Can you describe how that works?

Comment: @fprime: It's not magic. Someone needs to write a constructor for the Position class which takes an instance of that class as its only argument and returns a deep copy.

Comment: Not necessarily clone() does the deep copy: for example, returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)

Comment: Regarding third option, `clone()` - make sure Point implements `Cloneable`.

Comment: I want to create a deep copy of an Array of Objects, does Arrays.copyOf() create a deep copy ? These are objects of some custom classes which hasn't implemented the Cloneable interface.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954873/malicious-code-vulnerability-may-expose-internal-representation-by-incorporati/18954919?noredirect=1#comment55249093_18954919

Comment: rather than iterating through the array of objects and 'deep copying' them in either of the 3 above said methods, is there a way to 'Bulk Deep Copy' the entire array of objects to another ?

Comment: 1) No.  2) Given that there is no universal way to copy an `Object`, it is not possible to "deep copy" an arbitrary `Object[]`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```
data[i]=other.data[i];
```

You are just copying a list of references (assuming this is an array of objects). If you want to make a deep copy, you need to use `new` to create a new instance of each object in the array.

Comment: But where would I use new? In the loop?

Comment: Yes. In each iteration, create a `new` object and add it to `data`.

Comment: Ok Im confused. So would I remove `data=new Position[other.data.length];` for the code I have above and somehow add it into the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying:

```
data[i]=other.data[i]
```

You will want to make a copy constructor for `Position` (in other words, a constructor for Position that takes in another `Position` and copies the primitive data inside it) and say `data[i]=new Position(other.data[i]);`

Basically your "deep copy" constructor the `PositionList` is a copy constructor, although copy constructor does tend to indicate a deep copy, so the `deepCopy` parameter is unnecessary.

Comment: -1 clone makes a shallow copy not a deep copy. It can end up working OK for primitives and immutable objects, but don't confuse it with a deep copy.

Comment: @bwawok: that's true, I was assuming that `Position` was a POJO, and thus, `.clone()` would work.

Comment: How can I do this without clone?

Comment: @fprime: Then use a copy constructor, as my alternate solution said.  That said, I really should have put the "copy constructor" solution first, due to the fact that `.clone()` does have drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use:

```
function copy(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(x => Object
      .keys(x)
      .reduce((acc, y) => {
        acc[y] = x[y]
        return acc
      }, {}))
}
```

It only works on arrays with objects with a single level.

Answer (score -5):

This should make a "deep" copy

```
int [] numbers = { 2, 3, 4, 5};

int [] numbersClone = (int[])numbers.clone();
```

Comment: This will work for an array of primitives (like integers), but the question was about an array of objects.