# How to copy(memory) array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

Hi I want to copy an array...and I do not want to use "clone" which is slow to copy..
I tried arraycopy and copyOf, but it is not working

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            City[] tempCities = Arrays.copyOf(cities, cities.length) ;
            distance = 0;
            tempCities[i].setVisited();
}
```

but this modify my original array(cities). Does anyone know how to copy and not have another pointer to the same object

Comment: Why are you copying the array on each iteration of the loop? Also, define 'not working'.

Comment: So you want a deep copy in other words?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep copy of an object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947227/deep-copy-of-an-object-array)

Comment: is a copy of my city... I am using for TSP problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue is that you store *references* in the array. If you want the objects in the new array to be independent of the objects in the original array, you have to make a deep copy. For that, `cities[i].clone()` is your friend.

As to your performance issue, it could well be due to the fact that you copy the array during *every iteration of the loop*. This is very wasteful; a single copy would suffice.

Comment: the array cities is a type of City (coordinate x, coordinate y, boolean visited) the problem is the boolean value is not changing...

City[] tempCities = Arrays.copyOf(cities, cities.length);

when i change the property of tempCities, its changing even the property of the city. 
es: tempCities[i].setVisited(); this change cities[i] as visited, which I do not want... I tried clone too...but no use, and I cant use close because it is slow