# `Arrays,copyOf` didn't do a deep copy of objects as it is supposed to

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have class`Book` which can have many `Authors`. I pass few objects of class `Author` to the constructor of class `Book` then copy these objects by `Arrays.copyOF` but then if I change any `Author` data outside the object it will change everywhere so it means the copy has not been created.

I would like to create deep copy. Code is compiling and running with no errors.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Book {
    private String tytul;
    private int rokWydania;
    private Author[] autorzy;

    public Book(String tytul, int rokWydania, Author... autorzy) {
        this.tytul = tytul;
        this.rokWydania = rokWydania;
        this.autorzy = Arrays.copyOf(autorzy, autorzy.length);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "      Tytuł: " + tytul +"\nrok wydania: " + rokWydania + "\n";
        if(autorzy.length == 1)
            s+="      Autor: " + autorzy[0];
        else{
            s+="    Autorzy: " + autorzy[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < autorzy.length; i++)
                s+="\n             " + autorzy[i];
        }       
        return s + "\n\n";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author a1 = new Author("Isabel", "Allende", 1942);
        Author a2 = new Author("Manueala", "Gretkowska", 1964);
        Author a3 = new Author("Piotr", "Pietucha", 1954);

        Book b1 = new Book("Suma naszych dni", 2010, a1);
        Book b2 = new Book("Polka", 2001, a2);
        Book b3 = new Book("Sceny z życia pozamałżeńskiego", 2003, a2, a3);

        a2.zmienInformacje("Tove", "Jansson", 1956);
        Book b4 = new Book("Lato muminków", 2006, a2);

        System.out.println(b1);

        System.out.println(b2);

        System.out.println(b3);

        System.out.println(b4);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Author {
    private String imie, nazwisko;
    private int rokUrodzenia;

    public Author(String imie, String nazwisko, int rokUrodzenia) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.rokUrodzenia = rokUrodzenia;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public int getRokUrodzenia() {
        return rokUrodzenia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  imie + " " + nazwisko + " (ur. " + rokUrodzenia + ")";
    }

    public void zmienInformacje(String imie, String nazwisko, int rokUrodzenia) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.rokUrodzenia = rokUrodzenia;

    }

}
```

**Desired output:**

```
     Tytuł: Suma naszych dni
  rok wydania: 2010
        Autor: Isabel Allende (ur. 1942)


        Tytuł: Polka
  rok wydania: 2001
        Autor: Manuela Gretkowska (ur. 1964)


        Tytuł: Suma naszych dni
  rok wydania: 2010
      Autorzy: Manuela Gretkowska (ur. 1964)   
               Piotr Pietucha (ur. 1954)


        Tytuł: Lato muminków
  rok wydania: 2006
        Autor: Tove Jansson (ur. 1956)
```

**My output**

```
      Tytuł: Suma naszych dni
rok wydania: 2010
      Autor: Isabel Allende (ur. 1942)


      Tytuł: Polka
rok wydania: 2001
      Autor: Tove Jansson (ur. 1956)//WRONG


      Tytuł: Sceny z życia pozamałżeńskiego
rok wydania: 2003
    Autorzy: Tove Jansson (ur. 1956)//WRONG
             Piotr Pietucha (ur. 1954)


      Tytuł: Lato muminków
rok wydania: 2006
      Autor: Tove Jansson (ur. 1956)
```

Comment: Did it say it was going to? Probably not. So change the title to reflect the goal (and *search* for it) - e.g. "Create a deep copy of an Array"

Comment: @user2246674 Yes it did, there is whole other subject about it.

Comment: Nope, [it doesn't say it will make a deep copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,%20int)). There *is* a whole subject on this task - of which there are many existing answers/approaches. (e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947227/deep-copy-of-an-object-array))

Comment: @user2246674 But please do not be mean here. In my other subject there was whole discussion about valueOf sot this is not obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Robert, if the Javadoc of a method doesn't say it will perform a deep copy, it is simply a mistake on your part to assert that 'it is supposed to' do so. No amount of hand-waving or subject-changing or referring to uncited other topics can obscure that. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Arrays.copyOf` is working fine. Issue is in line `a2.zmienInformacje("Tove", "Jansson", 1956);` you are updating `Author a2` before printing `Book b2 and b3` .

Comment: You are right, but the problem is that teacher of my student does not understand `agregation` correctly. She missunderstands it with `composition`, altough she cannot implement any of these correctly so I have to do it "her way".

Comment: You're avoiding the issue. The only visible problem here is that you are attributing properties to `Arrays.copyOf()` that it does not have.