# Remove Object from Clone of Array of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My question is very basic but I am still not able to figure out how to do this. I have an array of ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Car>[] cars = new ArrayList[2];
```

Later in my program I am iterating over that array and I need to remove some objects from the ArrayList. However, since I cannot iterate over a list and remove the elements at the same time, I have decided to clone the array and remove the objects from the ArrayList of the clone. I noticed though, that the clone is referencing the same objects as the ones from the array. Below is some basic example:

```
    ArrayList<Car>[] cars = new ArrayList[2];
    cars[0] = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars[0].add(new Car("black"));
    cars[0].add(new Car("white"));

    cars[1] = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars[1].add(new Car("green"));
    cars[1].add(new Car("red"));

    ArrayList<Car>[] carClone = cars.clone();

    carClone[0].remove(0); // removes the objects from the ArrayList of clone as well as the ArrayList of the "real" array
```

In the above example you can see that it doesn't just remove the object from the clone, but also from the array. How can I overcome this problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: on what basis you wanna remove elements from `ArrayList` ? and also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947227/deep-copy-of-an-object-array

Comment: Why do you need an array of lists? Probably it is better to use list of lists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists